# Are the slopes of normal bundles of curves bounded from below?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a lower bound on the slope (i.e. ratio of degree to rank) of normal bundles of smooth projective curves embedded in smooth projective varieties?

Comment: It looks like Sasha has answered the question. I just wanted to point out that if you instead ask whether on a fixed variety $X$, there exists a bound that holds for all curves on $X$, I think this is a hard question; it seems like a reasonable analog of the bounded negativity conjecture to higher dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For instance the Hirzebruch surface $F_n$ contains a smooth rational curve with normal bundle $\mathcal{O}(-n)$ of slope $-n$.

Comment: What if we ask the ambient variety to have non-negative Kodaira dimension?

Comment: @Wenlong  Welcome new contributor.  That is still negative.  Fix a line in projective $3$-space.  For every positive integer $d$ you can find a smooth degree-$d$ hypersurface containing the line.  The normal bundle is an invertible sheaf on the line of degree $2-d$, which is arbitrarily negative as $d$ increases.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you. I hope it doesn't annoy you but what if we restrict to Calabi-Yau threefolds?